# Best way to select multiple items on a list using groupings

Tags: lists, checkboxes, multi-selection

First post here, so bare with me if I do something wrong.

Here is my issue:

Imagine that you have a list of students in a class. You want to be able to select all of them but you also want to be able to select students who are in a grouping.

Groupings could be named: "Ahead of the curve", "Trouble reading" etc. In the example below "Grouping of students" could be "Student 1" and "Student 3".

What makes it even more complicated is that some students can be a part of more than one grouping.

In addition we really want the solution to sale well, so classes with many groupings don't become a problem.

The image below is what we've been thinking but it seems complicated and does not scale well. If you select "grouping of students", the students from that grouping is selected in the list below.

Does anyone know of a way to solve this?

[image: quick sketch of problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you should be able to select single students as well.
I would seperate the group selection from the student selection something like this:

[image]

So the top box is like a filter for the students list (e.g. if group C is selected, only students in group C are visible) and in the list students can be selected individually.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Note that more than one group can be checked in the filterbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think we might go with a solution like this with a filter at the top. Probably going to be a drop down of sorts, where you add groupings to your filter. When no groupings are selected all students will be shown.

Comment: This is exactly what I proposed, apart from the fact that I thought it was for a mobile app, therefore I suggested to have a modal for the group selection :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to separate the groups selection task from the list of students.
1) Show a "Select group(s)" button at the top/bottom of your list.
2) When clicked, open a modal with a scrollable list of groups.
3) Once confirmed, the list of students show which one got selected and it's still editable by hand.

Leave the "All students" at the top of your list as you did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense, but lets say all students are selected and I want to deselect a particular group.

Comment: Let's say that the Groups modal is smart enough to recognise that if you selected in any way all the members of a group, that group gets selected. Just open the modal and deselect the group to uncheck those users. The task is slightly more advanced but that's due to the inherent complexity of groups management.